# Initramfs revisited (Error in Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: boot

My problem is different to others I have seen at the forum. 
When booting the system this is what appears:

```
[1.168307] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)
[1.1684911 ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCIO.SATO.SPT2_ GTF] (Node ffff8914550e1938),AE_NOT_FOUND(20160930/psparse-543)

[1.210601] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE. NOT_FOUND (201609 30/psargs-359)

 [1.210773] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCIO.SATO.SPT2._GTF] (Node ffff8914550e1938), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Then, I write 'exit' and this is what happens:

```
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory 

mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory

 /init: line 343: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
[17.080779] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=040000200 

[ 17.080779]

[17.080786] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.10.0-21-generic #23-Ubuntu

[17.080790] Hardware name: HSI MS-7850/H87-G41 PC Mate(MS-7850), BIOS V3.1 05/09/2013

[17.080793] Call Trace:

[ 17.080800] dump_stack+0x63/0x81

[ 17.080804] panic+0xe4/0x22d

[ 17.080808] do_exit+0xb09/0xb10

[ 17.080811] do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0

[ 17.080814] SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20

[ 17.080818] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xad

[17.080822] RIP: 0033:0x7ff7adaa7b38

[17.080824] RSP: 002b:00007ffe0a976738 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7

[17.080828] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007ff7adaa7b38
[ 17.060632] RDX: 0000000000000002 RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 0000000000000002

[17.080835] RBP: 0000562f9813642d8 R08: 00000000000000e7 R09: ffffffffffffff98

[ 17.080838] R10: 0000562f98b568f0 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000001
 [ 17.080842] R13: 0000562f98b5c630 R14: 0000562f98b64358 R15: 0000000000000000

[17.080864] Kernel Offset: Ox4c00000 from Oxffffffff81000000 (relocation range: Oxffffffff80000000-Oxffffffffbfffffff) 
[ 17.080869] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill initl exitcode=0x00000200
 [ 17.080869]
```

This is the second time I install Kubuntu 17.04 in a week, and the second time that it happens. I have Windows10 installed as well, but it works fine. ¿Any suggest?
Thank you, very much.

Comment: Is this a SSD or HDD? Did you reinstall Kubuntu, or do a fresh clean install? Is your motherboard BIOS up to date? Do you have ACPI enabled in your BIOS? Have you added any kernel parameters to your /etc/default/grub config file?

Comment: Thank you, Heynnema. It's a HDD. I did a clean install. My BIOS is from 2013 (I don't know if it is needed to update). The only reference to ACPI in my BIOS is: "ACPI Settings: -Power LED (Blinking or Dual Color)". I didn't add any kernel parameters to my grub file.

Comment: I'd check for a BIOS update at the manufacturer's web site. Is 17.04 something new, or did 16.x.x or 17.04 work here before?

Comment: Yes, I have visited MSI web and it is an update available. I'll try to update it (but I'm a little bit scared with a BIOS change). I installed 17.04, because was the last available ( I didn't work with Linux since long time ago)

Comment: I don't think those errors are relevant.  The relevant error is likely before those.  What does `cat /proc/cmdline` show at that prompt?  Also `lsblk`?

Comment: `cat /proc/cmdline  ---> BOOT_IMAGE = /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic    root=UUID=1acc2c44-3e14-48f9-9bf1-efd1d69c3565  ro quiet splash`                     `lsblk    --->  command not found `

Comment: Updated BIOS to last. Now, it doesn't appear any message before    `BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)`       but it doesn't boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

It looks like the BIOS update may have solved some evils, but the boot problem still exists. With the ACPI errors gone, we may have you reinstall the OS one more time, but first let's check your existing file system.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

To further check the hard disk hardware...

Use the `Disks` app to review the `SMART Data & Tests` data and run the tests. You could install `gsmartcontrol` to monitor the disk. Since this is a HDD, you could badblock the drive with `e2fsck -c -k /dev/sdb` while running  from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Answer (score 0):

I chose "Recovery mode" at boot, and this is what appeared:
`EXT4 - fs (sdb5):VFS: found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum. Run e2fsck?
mount: mounting /dev/sdb5 on /root failed: Bad message done.
initramfs`

I tried `fsck -f /` and this is what happened:

`error 2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /`
Then I tried with: `e2fsck -f /`

and began to appear some messages with `superblock invalid.... /dev/sdb5 was not cleanly mounted, check forced
... Inode 4325681 seems to contain garbage. Clear <y>?`

I accepted and appeared a lot of similar messages with different Inode numbers. At last I checked with 'a' option (to answer 'yes' to all questions).

Began to appear hundreds and hundreds of similar messages fixing the problems, and finally ended.
I made it again from the beggining with 'e2fsck' command. And the screen filled with negative numbers at a incredible speed. I waited 2,3, 4, 5 minutes and it didn't end, so I decided to reboot the computer.
Well, then I tried with an Ubuntu Live DVD.

Started GParted, confirmed 'sdb5' as Linux partition. Opened a terminal and typed again: fsck and e2fsck. Again the same thing as before, but  as I had it in a 'controlled' terminal window I didn't panic. At last the process ended. Made it again and the system didn't find any error, so I thought the problems had been corrected.
Rebooted the system, but 'oh, surprise', the GRUB menu did not appear. Instead of it appears: `Grub rescue`
I booted again with Live CD, and tried to reinstall the GRUB, but every time said me that was impossible to install GRUB at boot device (sda), so I didn't want to tempt fate and decided to maKe a clean install of Ubuntu.
Now, everything is OK, with my Boot menu for Windows or Ubuntu. I am going to work some days with Ubuntu without installing anything to check if the problem recreates or what happens.

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Of course. The answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: At the moment, the system works fine, but my printer and my sound card don't work (in previous installation of Ubuntu 17.04 they worked OK). The printer is listed with `lsusb : 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:6204 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet 5150c`           
But doesn't appear in CUPS `http://127.0.0.1:631/admin/` and I cannot print anything.
The sound card is also listed at PCI devices: `05:01.0   C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]`          
Do you think the problem could be the new BIOS firmware?

Comment: Doubtful it's the new BIOS... unless you need to change some parameters there... like the USB setting probably needs to be set to legacy. In System Settings, does the printer appear in the "Add Printer" dialog of the Printer panel, and the sound appear in the output tab of the Sound panel? If you can't figure it out, start separate, new, questions for each of those problems.

Comment: Printer fault is solved. If I cannot figure out Sound problem I'll ask in a new question. Thanks.

Comment: What was wrong with the printer?

Comment: I don't know, in fact. Today I have entered with CUPS at address :     `http://127.0.0.1:631`     and selecting the 'ADD PRINTER' option, it was available.

Comment: Since the BIOS update, and the reinstall of Ubuntu, would you say that your original problem has stabilized now?

Comment: Now, everything is working OK. The sound card problem is solved as well (run `alsamixer` in a terminal and choose 'Multichanel' as Analog Output.

Comment: I want to check the integrity of file system. ¿how can I do it? With the utility TESTDISK appear a lot of warnings  like these:     `Block_group_nr 625    recover_EXT2: "e2fsck -b 20480000 -B 4096 device" may be needed`     >`recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=729/745, s_mnt_count=0/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192`  >` recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096`    `recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 24413696`      `recover_EXT2: part_size 195309568` >`ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Backup_SB, 99 GB / 93 GiB`

Comment: Well. I booted with Live CD and checked with `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb5` and this is what showed: `Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes`   
`Inode 2103057 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes`    I fixed it. Is it relevant? Is there any way to check the integrity of file system?

Comment: Please don't place long text details in the comments... they're extremely difficult to read. Edit your question and paste them there. Also, start comments with `@username` to make sure that person gets the message. Like `@heynnema`. Your last comment didn't show the full fsck (sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb5) log. inode repair is easy, but you shouldn't see a whole lot of them over time, as long as you're shutting down properly.

Comment: @heynnema Ok, sorry. 
Now, when I start fsck it seems no problems found.   

    The last information appearing is `/dev/sdb5: 241554/6111232 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 2506878/24413696 blocks`  

    So it's supposed everything is working OK, isn't it?  

    Then is it enough to run fsck or do you think is needed to check it with another command?

Comment: You could use the `Disks` app to review the `SMART Data & Tests` data and run the tests. You could install `gsmartcontrol` to monitor the disk. Since this is a HDD, you could badblock the drive with `e2fsck -c -k /dev/sdb` (you may have to do this from a Live DVD/USB).

Comment: @heynnema  . I have checked with `gsmartcontrol` and it hasn't  found any error, so I suppose from now everything is going to work fine. Thank you.